# Removing null at beginning and end of array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

Looking for an algorithm that will remove null that occurs at the **beginning** and **end** of the array and nothing in between that is O(n)

For example:

```
[null, null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null] -> [1, 2, 3]

[null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, null, null] -> [1, 2, null, 3]

[1, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, null] -> [1, null, 2, 3, null, 4]

[null, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5] -> [2, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5]
```

Comment: You can identify the positions of the first and last elements with one scan, so O(n), and then just [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), and I assume that's O(n) too, if not better internally.

Comment: Oops, I meant [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), to return a new copy of the trimmed array. But then maybe splice is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit chunky but works.

```js
const tests = [[null, null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null],
[null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, null, null],
[1, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, null],
[null, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5]];

const strip = (arr) => {
  const end = arr.length-(arr.reverse().findIndex(a => a != null));
  const start = arr.reverse().findIndex(a => a != null);
  return arr.slice(start, end);
};

tests.forEach(a => console.log(strip(a)));
```

One single loop, checking start and end.

```js
const tests = [[null, null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null],
[null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, null, null],
[1, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, null],
[null, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5],
[null, null, null, null, null],
[null, 1, null, null, null, null]
];

const strip = (arr) => {
  let start = -1, end = -1, i = 0, x = arr.length - 1;
  while(start === -1 || end === -1) {
    if(start === -1 && arr[i] !== null) {
        start = i;
    }
    if(end === -1 && arr[x] !== null) {      
        end = x+1;
    }
    if(i === x) return [];
    x--;
    i++;
  }
  return arr.slice(start, end);
};




tests.forEach(a => console.log(strip(a)));
```

Ok, here is a super super simple solution.

```js
const tests = [[null, null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null],
[null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, null, null],
[1, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, null],
[null, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5],
[null, null, null, null, null]
];

const strip = (arr) => {
  while(arr[0] === null && arr.length > 0) {
    arr.shift();
  }
  while(arr[arr.length-1] === null && arr.length > 0) {
    arr.pop();
  }
  return arr;
};

tests.forEach(a => console.log(strip(a)));
```

Comment: I don't think it's worth reversing the array twice just so you can use findIndex - that's too much work. It would be easier to just scan with `for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)` I'd think.

Comment: Single loop, no reverse and minimum scan in second example.

Comment: Nice. I'm not sure there's any benefit to merging the two scan loops, and I'd guess it won't cope with an input array of all nulls.

Comment: Assume empty array is desired for all nulls?

Comment: I'd guess so? But now you've run into the danger of doing both loops together: x and i meeting isn't the limit. Try [null, 1, null, null, null, null, null]: x and i will meet in the middle before you find the right value of end and you'll assume it's empty. And if the length is even then x and i will cross and not equal each other anyway.

Comment: The solution at the end using `arr.shift();` is O(n^2) time because `shift` is an O(n) operation.

Comment: @kaya3 cut me a little slack here :). Good spot though.

Comment: first one returns `[null]` for array of `null`s

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively small solution that should be O(n). You do one pass to get the start and end positions of your array and then another pass when you do a `.slice`.

```js
const trimmer = arr => {
  const positions = arr.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
    if(el !== null) {
      acc[1] = i + 1;
      if (acc[0] === undefined) acc[0] = i;
    }
    return acc;
  }, [undefined, undefined]);
  return arr.slice(...positions);
}

console.log(trimmer([null, null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null]));
console.log(trimmer([null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, null, null]));
console.log(trimmer([1, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, null]));
console.log(trimmer([null, null, 2, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

that would be the most efficient solution

```
function removeNullsFromEdges(array) {
  let indexOfFirstNumber = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== null) {
      indexOfFirstNumber = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  let indexOfLastNumber = array.length;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] !== null) {
      indexOfLastNumber = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return array.slice(indexOfFirstNumber, indexOfLastNumber + 1);
}
```